# For some reason java can't find any of my references in any of my classes for android

Tags: reference

Apparently I've done something I'm not aware of

All my classes now have warnings on all layout references and button references

for example the warning  "consultrequest cannot be resolved or is not a field" is present with each of these within this class

consultrequest,
nametext,
phonetext,
casedescriptiontext,
sendbutton

```
package com.Zohan.hozo;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ConsultationReq extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.consultrequest);

    EditText Nameinputtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    EditText Phoneinputtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonetext);
    EditText Casedescriptinputtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.casedescriptiontext);
    Button ConsultationSendbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    ConsultationSendbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ConsultationReq.this, MacAttack.class));
            } 
    });    
}
```

}

if someone has advice on how I can fix this I thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using eclipse, clean your project.

Comment: I think my computer is just slow it takes a while for clean to take effect